# How can I perform data denormalization on GCP?

Tags: google-bigquery, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to denormalize and join three tables named order, order_item, and user in Bigquery. I already have a pipeline that is used to update those tables using pubsub and dataflow. Now I want to create a pipeline that updates a new, denormalized table whenever an update or insert happens in any of three tables mentioned. These updates on order and order_item must be in sync, and user should be joined only when an insert happens at order(in order to show status of user when a new order is created).

I came up with two solutions so far.

- One is to capture changes on each table when a message from pubsub is read via dataflow and then enriched with latest corresponding records from denormalized table. Lastly, old record is replaced by the new record.
- The other one is querying order and order_item tables to get updated or newly inserted rows then join them using bigquery sql, consequently appending results to denormalized table. This job is ran on a regular basis with help of Airflow.

### order

id (primary key)
last_updated_at
created_at
user_id (foreign key)

=====================

### order_item

id (primary key)
last_updated_at
created_at
order_id (foreign key)

=====================

### user

id (primary key)
last_updated_at
created_at

I am not very familiar with dataflow, and I could not come across any tutorial or example that shows how I can do the job using it(although there are sample codes showing how an ETL operation can be done, there are no solution to synchronisation problem). Are there any examples that I can look into, and which alternative seems more efficient?

Comment: Having some questions regarding to your question:
1. Are you having three pubsub topics (user, order, order_item)?
2. You want to make order and order_item updated in sync. What does this mean?
3. After order and order_item table have new updates, you want to order_item join order on order_id, then join on user table by user_id, right?

Comment: 1. I have only one pubsub topic for all three of the tables.
2. I mean for example in the final table, there should not be an outdated order record joined with other tables resulting mistakes in the table. The newly added rows must always include latest values of each table except user.
3. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

I want to preface this with that BigQuery is not a transactional database, and thus trying to work in consistency after the fact is going to be very hard. In this case I would suggest using either Cloud Spanner or Cloud SQL (see this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-Google-Cloud-Spanner-and-Cloud-SQL) for the difference between the two). For example, this is very easy in Cloud Spanner. There is the notion of [transactions](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/transactions) in which you can keep the denormalized table perfectly in sync with the other tables at any given time.

On the bright side, if you are okay with your denormalized table to potentially be out of sync with your other tables then there are easier solutions out there.

In this case, I am assuming that it is cost-prohibitive to switch to another storage offering and that it is okay for the tables to potentially out of sync. Cloud Dataflow is a great product if you need to do batch or streaming data analytics, but the API becomes awkward to use when in use cases like yours (event-based processing). Your first solution seems like the best if you want to keep using Dataflow, but I would actually suggest using something like [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/).

The set-up would look like this:

1. Pub/Sub writes to Dataflow
2. Dataflow writes updated rows to BigQuery
3. Dataflow writes a Pub/Sub message containing the delta (e.g. insert row X into order, update Y row in order_item).
4. Have a Cloud Function that triggers on the Pub/Sub subscription that has your specified logic to read the correct rows from the normalized tables then write to the denormalized tables.

Your Cloud Function might look something like the following (written in Javascript), inspired from [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/use-cloud-spanner). :

```
// Import the Google Cloud client library
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
const dataset = bigquery.dataset('my-dataset');
const orders = dataset.table('orders');
const order_items = dataset.table('order_items');
const users = dataset.table('users');
const denorm = dataset.table('denormalized');

function GetOrder(order_id) {
  let [order] = await orders.row(order_id);
  return order;
}

function GetOrderItem(...) { ... }
function GetUser(...) { ... }

/**
 * HTTP Cloud Function.
 *
 * @param {Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
exports.get = (req, res) => {
  const method = req.params.method;
  const table = req.params.table;

  let query = '';
  if (method === 'insert' && table === 'order') {
    let order = GetOrder(req.params.order_id);
    let order_item = GetOrderItem(order.id);
    let user = GetUser(order.user_id);
    denorm.insert({
      ORDER: order.my_data,
      ORDER_ITEM: order_item.my_data,
      USER: user.my_data
    });
  } else if ( ... ) { ... }
}
```

[How to insert](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigtable/1.0.x/Table#insert)
[How to query](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigtable/1.0.x/Table#getRows)